# Implement solution of differential equations system using exponential matrix in Julia

Tags: arrays, matrix, julia, differential-equations, exponentiation

I try to reproduce the example, in Julia, that I show in the figure and taken from [Matrix Exponentiation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/matrix-exponentiation/)
[image]

I show you how far I have managed to reproduce the exercise in Julia. But I don't know how to introduce the vector t, for a range of interest, for example t = -3: 0.25: 3. in the matrix: [exp (u1 * t 0; 0 exp (u2 * t], u1 u2 eigenvalues.

```
Julia>A=[0 1;1 0]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  1
 1  0

F=eigen(A)
Eigen{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2},Array{Float64,1}}
values:
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 -1.0
  1.0
vectors:
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.707107  0.707107
  0.707107  0.707107

D = diagm(exp.(F.values))
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.367879  0.0
 0.0       2.71828

P = F.vectors
13:06:08->>2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.707107  0.707107
  0.707107  0.707107
```

Comment: Just use `exp(A*t)*u0`. There's not much more to it.

Comment: Note that if you look at what it does, it ends up doing basically what you would have written anyway

Comment: is it possible to improve the code?

Comment: ```C=[0 1;1 0]
x0=[1 0]
∆t = .25
T = exp(C*∆t) 
x = x0
x1 =x0 
for i = 1:100
x = x*T #repeatedly multiply by T
x1=vcat(x1, x) # & store current x1(t) in the array x1
end```

Answer (score 1):

On the site [Fabian Dablander](https://fabiandablander.com/r/Linear-Love.html)
code is shown codes in R that implement the solution.
These are the scripts brought to Julia:

```
using Plots
using LinearAlgebra

#Solving differential equations using matrix exponentials
A=[-0.20 -1;1 0] #[-0.40 -1;1 0.45] A=[0 1;1 0]
x0=[1 1]# [1 1] x0=[0.25 0.25] x0=[1 0]
tmax=20
n=1000
ts=LinRange(0,tmax,n)
x = Array{Float64}(undef, 0, 0)
x=x0
for i in 1:n
x=vcat(x,x0*exp(A*ts[i]))
end
plot(x)
plot(x[:,1],x[:,2])


#Solving differential equations finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors
A=[-0.20 -1;1 0] #A=[-0.40 -1;1 0.45] A=[0 1;1 0]
x0=[1 1]# [1 1] x0=[0.25 0.25] x0=[1 0]
tmax=20
n=500
# compute eigenvectors and eigenvalues
  eig = eigen(A)
  E =eig.vectors
  λ=eig.values
# solve for the initial conditon
C =E\x0'
# create time steps
ts=LinRange(0,tmax,n)
x = Array{Float64}(undef,n, size(A,2))
for i in 1:n
   x[i,:]=real.(C'*diagm(exp.(λ*ts[i]))*E)
 end
plot(x)
plot(x[:,1],x[:,2])
```